# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'android/databinding/DataBindingComponent.java'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-databinding, android-studio-3.0

I got this error during build in android studio:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
>
> > More than one file was found with OS independent path 'android/databinding/DataBindingComponent.java'

I used [this library](https://github.com/drstranges/DataBinding_For_RecyclerView) to apply generic adapter with databinding.
My app already turn on `databinding`

```
  dataBinding {
    enabled = true
  }
```

The example from this library works fine, but don't know why it  duplicates `DataBindingComponent` in my app.
Is there any clue to figure out it?

Comment: Maybe you should *switch off* the databinding for library? Finding the subproject and performing: `project.android.databinding.enabled = false`. Do not ask how to find the subproject, I do not know 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I meet this problem when I update my Android Studio to 3.0 version.
fixed by add packagingOptions:

```
android{
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'android/databinding/DataBinderMapper.java'
        exclude 'android/databinding/DataBindingComponent.java'
        exclude 'android/databinding/DynamicUtil.java'
    }
}
```